# ValueError .. The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.11.11 / Python 2.7.5
I have a Photo model in form to upload multiple images. There is an error with this model : https://ibb.co/m3XLDn

Photo model :

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    produit = models.CharField(
        _("Produit (code utile pour le tri des choix):"), 
        max_length=2000, 
        blank=True, 
        null=False
        )
    legende = models.CharField(
        _("Légende:"), 
        max_length=200, 
        blank=True, 
        null=False
        )
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='fiche_image', 
        blank=True, 
        null=False
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.produit or "undefined"
        # return str(self.produit)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['produit', 'legende', 'image']
```

I'm not sure what causing the problem.

new_photo view :

```
def new_photo(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    photo_form = forms.PhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="photo")
    if photo_form.is_valid():
        photo = photo_form.save()
        photo.save()
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"id": photo.pk, "produit": photo.produit, "legende": photo.legende, "name": photo.image.name}))
    else:
        HttpResponseBadRequest()
elif request.method == "GET":
    print(models.Photo.objects.all())
    photos = {}
    for p in models.Photo.objects.all():
        photos[p.pk] = {"produit": p.produit, "legende": p.legende, "name": p.image.name}
        print(p.image.name)
        print(p.image.url)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(photos))
```

Comment: What code is causing the problem? Usually when `ImageField` says something like this, it is telling the truth.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a file associated with the `Photo` object. so, it is throwing an error by saying "'image' attribute has no file associated with it". Because the field `image` allows null values to be stored. In such cases there will be no file associated with `Photo` object.

You can check like below

```
obj = Photo.objects.get(pk=<some int>)
if obj.image:
    print(obj.image.url)
else:
    print("No image assigned to object")
```

Comment: in which file ?

Comment: @CGS63 in your `apps/craft/views.py`  line number `1341` you have code `p.image.url`. It's causing the error.

Comment: question updated to add new_photo view. I tried the above but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: Any help please ?